# docker unzip file on run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfiles which work, but my image is heavy.
I would like to unzip only on start! How can I do that?
I would like to execute `dockerStatScript.sh` just on start, and after `"pm2-runtime", "pm2_conf.json"`

I have try everything... I don't get it

thank for your help

---

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:12-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash && \
    apk add postgresql-libs libpq zip unzip tree

WORKDIR /app

COPY docker/dockerStatScript.sh .

RUN chmod +x dockerStatScript.sh

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY app_prod/build/2.6.3/app.zip Zapp.zip
COPY app_prod/build/2.6.3/node_modules.zip Znode_modules.zip
COPY app_prod/build/2.6.3/config.zip Zconfig.zip

RUN ["/bin/bash","dockerStatScript.sh"]

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "pm2_conf.json" ]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

To compress immage use

```
docker image build --compress {rest-of-the-build-arguments-here}
```

to start `dockerStatScript.sh` after `"pm2-runtime", "pm2_conf.json"`
you will have to create a wrapper shell script like `startup.sh` with content

```
./pm2-runtime.sh pm2_conf.json
./dockerStatScript.sh
```

add it to the docker image like you did for `dockerStatScript.sh`. i.e.

```
COPY docker/startup.sh .
RUN chmod +x startup.sh
```

and than replace these:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash","dockerStatScript.sh"]
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "pm2_conf.json" ]
```

with this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/app/startup.sh"]
```

and start container with out parameters because entrypoint going to "startup.sh" on each container start.

here is a helpful link which explains startup options:

https://dev.to/lasatadevi/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint-34e0.

hope i didn't do any typos :)

**UPDATE:**

you can use 
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/app/startup.sh"]`

or

`CMD ["/bin/bash","/app/startup.sh"]`

or omit entrypoint and cmd and just start container with `/app/startup.sh` as parameter. i.e. `docker run image-name "/app/startup.sh"` - i am usually using this wa because it gives more flexibility what to run during debug time.

Make sure that your sh file doesn't exit until you need your container to stop.

Comment: Do you mean `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` here?  (There's no particular reason to want `ENTRYPOINT` and it makes a couple of routine operations more complicated; I'd reserve it for a wrapper script that does some first-time setup and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.)

Comment: you are right, cmd also can be used in this case. updated answer.